# xml formatting dropped when more than 1 record returned

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a PHP page that creates XML output from a MySQL query, when it is returning one set of records, it displays it nicely with XML formatting.

However when it returns more than one set of records, the XML formatting is dropped. But both requested record sets are returned.

I edit the database records for triggering one or more sets of records to be returned "WHERE wp_hud_display.user_id = 1", each of the records when run on their own, displays clearly in XML, so it cant be some weird character in the database causing the XML formatting to be dropped.

PHP Page

```
<?php    
// create a dom document with encoding utf8 
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "root";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "";
$config['db_name']    = "tasmanhud";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);

//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT
  wp_hud_display.id,
  wp_hud_display.name,
  wp_hud_display.resolution,
  wp_hud_display.user_id,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_1,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_1,
  wp_hud_display.layer_1,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_2,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_2,
  wp_hud_display.layer_2,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_3,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_3,
  wp_hud_display.layer_3,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_4,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_4,
  wp_hud_display.layer_4,
  wp_hud_instrument.inst_id AS inst1_id,
  wp_hud_instrument.name AS inst1_name,
  wp_hud_instrument.image_file AS inst1_image,
  wp_hud_instrument.font_type AS inst1_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument.font_size AS inst1_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id AS inst2_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.name AS inst2_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.image_file AS inst2_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.font_type AS inst2_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.font_size AS inst2_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id AS inst3_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.name AS inst3_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.image_file AS inst3_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.font_type AS inst3_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.font_size AS inst3_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id AS inst4_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.name AS inst4_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.image_file AS inst4_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.font_type AS inst4_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.font_size AS inst4_fs
FROM wp_hud_display
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1 = wp_hud_instrument.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_1
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2 = wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_2
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3 = wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_3
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4 = wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id
WHERE wp_hud_display.user_id = 1
GROUP BY wp_hud_display.id";

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("wp_hud_displays");
/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$hud_display_group = $domtree->createElement("hud_display_group");
$hud_display_group = $xmlRoot->appendChild($hud_display_group);


    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
       while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
$hud_display = $domtree->createElement("hud_display");
$hud_display = $hud_display_group->appendChild($hud_display);

$instrument_id_1 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_1");
$instrument_id_1 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_1);

$instrument_id_2 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_2");
$instrument_id_2 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_2);

$instrument_id_3 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_3");
$instrument_id_3 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_3);

$instrument_id_4 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_4");
$instrument_id_4 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_4);

    /* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */

$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('id',$result_array['id']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['name']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('resolution',$result_array['resolution']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('user_id',$result_array['user_id']));

// Instrument 1
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_1',$result_array['instrument_id_1']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst1_id']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst1_name']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst1_image']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst1_ft']));  
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst1_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_1',$result_array['x_loc_1']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_1',$result_array['y_loc_1']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_1',$result_array['layer_1']));

// Instrument 2
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_2',$result_array['instrument_id_2']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst2_id']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst2_name']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst2_image']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst2_ft']));  
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst2_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_2',$result_array['x_loc_2']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_2',$result_array['y_loc_2']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_2',$result_array['layer_2']));

// Instrument 3 
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_3',$result_array['instrument_id_3']));
    $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst3_id']));       $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst3_name']));
$instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst3_image']));
$instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst3_ft']));  $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst3_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_3',$result_array['x_loc_3']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_3',$result_array['y_loc_3']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_3',$result_array['layer_3']));



    // Instrument 4
 $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_4',$result_array['instrument_id_4']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst4_id']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst4_name']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst4_image']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst4_ft']));  
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst4_fs'])); $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_4',$result_array['x_loc_4']));
    $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_4',$result_array['y_loc_4']));
    $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_4',$result_array['layer_4']));

            }
        }
    // get the xml printed 

       echo $domtree->saveXML();

    //send the xml header to the browser

    header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

    ?>
```

One Record XML Output

```
<wp_hud_displays>
 <hud_display_group>
   <hud_display>
     <instrument_id_1></instrument_id_1>
     <instrument_id_2></instrument_id_2>
     <instrument_id_3></instrument_id_3>
     <instrument_id_4></instrument_id_4>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>test display</name>
   <resolution>1080p</resolution>
   <user_id>1</user_id>
   <instrument_id_1>1</instrument_id_1>
   <x_loc_1>89</x_loc_1>
   <y_loc_1>79</y_loc_1>
   <layer_1>1</layer_1>
   <instrument_id_2>2</instrument_id_2>
   <x_loc_2>988</x_loc_2>
   <y_loc_2>98</y_loc_2>
   <layer_2>1</layer_2>
   <instrument_id_3>3</instrument_id_3>
   <x_loc_3>89</x_loc_3>
   <y_loc_3>90</y_loc_3>
   <layer_3>1</layer_3>
   <instrument_id_4>4</instrument_id_4>
   <x_loc_4>67</x_loc_4>
   <y_loc_4>76</y_loc_4>
   <layer_4>1</layer_4>
  </hud_display>
 </hud_display_group>
</wp_hud_displays>
```

More than one record output

```
1test1_gauge001-2_zpsdbe86ca1f.jpg11PID_DISTANCE30100002500101223dfd34412sdf34534056Arail122test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000002test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000003new gaugedfsgsdfgfd435430PID_COOLANT_TEMP2434534541023324000000003new gaugedfsgsdfgfd435430PID_COOLANT_TEMP2434534541023324000000004Bla100.jpg2702334395910299000000004Bla100.jpg2702334395910299000000002test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000001test display1080p118979129889813899014677612dsfdsfsd720p12321342323213224232123143423444342
```

Could it be something to do with the WHILE loop?, unable to create another set of "wp_hud_display.id" records

Answer (score 0):

Very strange results in stripping the XML tags and leaving only the values on records after the first. Possibly, it may be due to the deprecated `mysql()` functions that Wordpress may no longer support.

Consider using [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) with a try/catch on the connection, iterating through the STH object. I also add a document output for you to see if contents differ between screen and file

Additionally, you could take advantage of a `for loop` across elements since tag names change only by the 1-4 instrument indicators:

```
<?php    
// create a dom document with encoding utf8 
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "root";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "";
$config['db_name']    = "tasmanhud";

//connect to host
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$config['mysql_host'];dbname=$config['db_name']",$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);    
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //select all items in table
    $sql = "SELECT
      wp_hud_display.id,
      wp_hud_display.name,
      wp_hud_display.resolution,
      wp_hud_display.user_id,
      wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1,
      wp_hud_display.x_loc_1,
      wp_hud_display.y_loc_1,
      wp_hud_display.layer_1,
      wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2,
      wp_hud_display.x_loc_2,
      wp_hud_display.y_loc_2,
      wp_hud_display.layer_2,
      wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3,
      wp_hud_display.x_loc_3,
      wp_hud_display.y_loc_3,
      wp_hud_display.layer_3,
      wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4,
      wp_hud_display.x_loc_4,
      wp_hud_display.y_loc_4,
      wp_hud_display.layer_4,
      wp_hud_instrument.inst_id AS inst1_id,
      wp_hud_instrument.name AS inst1_name,
      wp_hud_instrument.image_file AS inst1_image,
      wp_hud_instrument.font_type AS inst1_ft,
      wp_hud_instrument.font_size AS inst1_fs,
      wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id AS inst2_id,
      wp_hud_instrument_1.name AS inst2_name,
      wp_hud_instrument_1.image_file AS inst2_image,
      wp_hud_instrument_1.font_type AS inst2_ft,
      wp_hud_instrument_1.font_size AS inst2_fs,
      wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id AS inst3_id,
      wp_hud_instrument_2.name AS inst3_name,
      wp_hud_instrument_2.image_file AS inst3_image,
      wp_hud_instrument_2.font_type AS inst3_ft,
      wp_hud_instrument_2.font_size AS inst3_fs,
      wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id AS inst4_id,
      wp_hud_instrument_3.name AS inst4_name,
      wp_hud_instrument_3.image_file AS inst4_image,
      wp_hud_instrument_3.font_type AS inst4_ft,
      wp_hud_instrument_3.font_size AS inst4_fs
      FROM wp_hud_display
      LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument
        ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1 = wp_hud_instrument.inst_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_1
        ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2 = wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_2
        ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3 = wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_3
        ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4 = wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id
      WHERE wp_hud_display.user_id = 1
      GROUP BY wp_hud_display.id";

    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("wp_hud_displays");
/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$hud_display_group = $domtree->createElement("hud_display_group");
$hud_display_group = $xmlRoot->appendChild($hud_display_group);


while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  

    $hud_display = $domtree->createElement("hud_display");
    $hud_display = $hud_display_group->appendChild($hud_display);

    $instrument_id_1 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_1");
    $instrument_id_1 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_1);

    $instrument_id_2 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_2");
    $instrument_id_2 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_2);

    $instrument_id_3 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_3");
    $instrument_id_3 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_3);

    $instrument_id_4 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_4");
    $instrument_id_4 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_4);

    /* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */
    $id = $domtree->createElement('id',$row['id']);
    $hud_display->appendChild($id);

    $name = $domtree->createElement('name',$row['name']);
    $hud_display->appendChild($name);

    $resolution = $domtree->createElement('resolution',$row['resolution']);
    $hud_display->appendChild($resolution);

    $user_id = $domtree->createElement('user_id',$row['user_id']);
    $hud_display->appendChild($user_id);

    // Instruments 1 - 4
    for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

       ${'instrument_id_'.$i} = $domtree->createElement('instrument_id_'.$i,$row['instrument_id_'.$i]);
       $hud_display->appendChild(${'instrument_id_'.$i});

       ${'inst'.$i.'_id'} = $domtree->createElement('inst_id',$row['inst'.$i.'_id']);
       ${'instrument_id_'.$i}->appendChild(${'inst'.$i.'_id');

       ${'inst'.$i.'_name'} = $domtree->createElement('name',$row['inst'.$i.'_name']);
       ${'instrument_id_'.$i}->appendChild(${'inst'.$i.'_name'});

       ${'inst'.$i.'_image'} = $domtree->createElement('image_name',$row['inst'.$i.'_image']);
       ${'instrument_id_'.$i}->appendChild(${'inst'.$i.'_image'});

       ${'inst'.$i.'_ft'} = $domtree->createElement('font_type',$row['inst'.$i.'_ft']);
       ${'instrument_id_'.$i}->appendChild(${'inst'.$i.'_ft'});

       ${'inst'.$i.'_fs'} = $domtree->createElement('font_size',$row['inst'.$i.'_fs']);
       ${'instrument_id_'.$i}->appendChild(${'inst'.$i.'_fs'});

       ${'x_loc_'.$i} = $domtree->createElement('x_loc_'.$i,$row['x_loc_'.$i]);
       $hud_display->appendChild(${'x_loc_'.$i});

       ${'y_loc_'.$i} = $domtree->createElement('y_loc_'.$i,$row['y_loc_'.$i]);
       $hud_display->appendChild(${'y_loc_'.$i});

       ${'layer_'.$i} = $domtree->createElement('layer_'.$i,$row['layer_'.$i]);
       $hud_display->appendChild(${'layer_'.$i});
    }

}

// get the xml printed 
echo $domtree->saveXML();

// saving xml to document 
file_put_contents("XML_WP_Output.xml", $domtree->saveXML());

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

// closing db connection
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I gave it a try and had not much luck, on returning one set of records, I had the XML formatting display without any results.
And for returning more than one set of results, I had a blank screen return. May not be a MySQL connection issue, But a problem in the WHILE LOOP?

Comment: @Dan. Sorry, in my original post I used your fetch variable, `$result_array()` instead of my PDO fetch variable, `$row`. Hence the error and blank screen. Adjust on your end or consider my edit which I also employed a `for loop` since all your node names are the same except instrument numbers, 1-4. I also `createElement` first before `appendChild`.

Comment: Thanks for that, its working well for the joined tables, how do I need to edit it so the primary table results show up as well? eg id, name, resolution, user_id. 
The elements created before the FOR line

Comment: Wow! @Dan, I did it again! I kept your `$result_array()` instead of the new `$row()`. I just edited. Serves me right for changing OP's code!

Comment: Thanks Parfait, that's working well. I've added some more results that come from the joined tables, however it displays up to half the results and then drops the formatting.  Is there a limit on the number of entries returned from a query that xml can't handle with joined tables or is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Up to half? If you added instruments, did you adjust loop past the max limit of 4? There should be no limit on XML content unless WP sets a page limit. XML files can be over 1GB with thousands of nodes! Check the .xml doc output in root folder.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been busy with work, There are four instruments, and they load fine, it is when you add more records to be return for each instrument.
i.e instrument_id_1 works when it returns 17 columns from that table, but drops the XML when asked to return 18 or more.
I tried as you suggested, increasing the limit, but that is if there is more than four instruments to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why Firefox has issues with the XML formatting when returning my query.

Turns out Firefox has a 4K XML node limit
[Firefox 4K XML Node Limit](http://www.coderholic.com/firefox-4k-xml-node-limit/)

When testing my query in IE, it works fine, and loading the output .xml file post query in Firefox is also fine.

That will teach me for not testing with different browsers!

Thanks for you help guys with this problem, I understand a bit more about XML now.